# Word Break algorithm

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to implement the "Word Break" algorithm.

Problem:
Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

Note:

The same word in the dictionary may be reused multiple times in the segmentation.
You may assume the dictionary does not contain duplicate words.

Example:

```
Input: s = "leetcode", wordDict = ["leet", "code"]
Output: true
Explanation: Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".
```

My solution:

```
var wordBreak = function(s, wordDict) {
    if(!wordDict || wordDict.length === 0)
        return false;
    
    while(wordDict.length > 0 || s.length > 0) {
        const word = wordDict.shift();
        const index = s.indexOf(word);
        if(index === -1) {
            return false;
        }
        s = s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(index+word.length, s.length);
    }
    
    return s.length === 0 && wordDict.length === 0 ? true : false;
};
```

It works for the example (input) above. However it fails for the input below.

```
Input: s = "applepenapple", wordDict = ["apple", "pen"]
Output: true
Explanation: Return true because "applepenapple" can be segmented as "apple pen apple".
             Note that you are allowed to reuse a dictionary word.
```

How can I keep track of words that I already eliminate and check it at the end. This input above, the remaining s string contains "apple" which is in the word dictionary, so the output should be true.

Thanks

Comment: Is it allowed that in the dict there are words that parts of other words like ['part', 'partner']?

Comment: Do you really mean to use `shift`? That modifies your `wordDict` such that it can't be reused. Also, are you asking if the input string only contains substrings that are in `wordDict`, or are you asking to put spaces around every instance of a word from `wordDict`? In other words, what do you expect with the string "leetecode" (putting an "e" between leet and code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple Javascript solution.**

This loops through the wordDict array and checks if each word exist in the str. If it doesn't that is when the indexOf the word return -1, the function returns false. However, if the words in the wordDict array are in the string, it returns true at the end of the for loop.

```
const wordBreak =(str, wordDict)=>{
    if (!wordDict || wordDict.length === 0) return false
    for(let i=0; I<wordDict.length; i++){
        const dictIndex = str.indexOf(wordDict[i])
        if(dictIndex === -1){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem I met two years ago in a different context, i.e., query tokenization. In my case, the number of words in the dictionary was in the order of several million, therefore a recursive approach looking each time for a different word of the dictionary was not practicable. Furthermore, I needed to apply dynamic programming to solve the task for strict efficiency reasons.

First of all, I suggest you to use the [AhoCorasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) to find the words within your search string. The algorithm looks for an arbitrary number of patterns in a string in linear time in the length of the string regardless of the number of patterns to find (no more number of words times length of the string operation, indeed each find of a word in a string needs to scan the entire string..).
Luckily, I found a javascript implementation of the algorithm [here](https://github.com/BrunoRB/ahocorasick/blob/master/src/main.js).

Using the code linked above and dynamic programming to track the words appearing in your string, I wrote the following javascript solution:

```
function wordBreak(s, wordDict) {
    const len = s.length;
    const memoization_array_words = new Array(len).fill(null);
    const memoization_array_scores = new Array(len).fill(0);

    const wordScores = {};
    wordDict.forEach(function(word) {
        wordScores[word] = 1
    });

    automata = new AhoCorasick(wordDict);
    results = automata.search(s);

    results.forEach(function(result) {
        // result[0] contains the end position
        // result[1] contains the list of words ending in that position
        const end_pos = result[0];
        result[1].forEach(function(word) {
            const prev_end_pos = end_pos - word.length;
            const prev_score = (prev_end_pos == -1) ? 0 : memoization_array_scores[prev_end_pos];
            const score = prev_score + wordScores[word];
            if (score > memoization_array_scores[end_pos]) {
                memoization_array_words[end_pos] = word;
                memoization_array_scores[end_pos] = score;
            }
        });
    });

    if (memoization_array_words[len-1] == null) {
        return false;
    }
    solution = []
    var pos_to_keep = len - 1;
    while (pos_to_keep >= 0) {
        const word = memoization_array_words[pos_to_keep];
        solution.push(word);
        pos_to_keep -= word.length;
    }
    return solution.reverse()
}
```

where `memoization_array_words` and `memoization_array_scores` are filled left to right when we meet a word occurring after a previous one or at the beginning of the string `s`. The code should be autoesplicative, but if you need any explanation write me a comment, please.
As a plus, I associated a score to each word (here is 1 for simplicity) that allows you to distinguish between the different solutions. For instance, if you associate to each word an importance score, you will end up with the tokenization with the greatest score. In the code above, the tokenization with the highest number of words.

Answer (score 1):

**Extended version:** I testing over the wordDict with **some** if there is one of the worde that beginns at the test-string (indexOf==0). If so I shorten the string about the length of the word and call the function recursivly with the shortened string. Otherwise the string is not splitable and I return false. I go this way on till an error occurs or the length of the string is 0 and I win because everything goes allright.
**Remark:** The error when the WordBreak is not clearly like with  s= "cars" wordDict = ["car","ca","rs"] is now fixed. For this I calling in the some-methode the algorithm recursivly. So if one way stops before ending I go backwards and search for alternatives till I found one or there is no possibility left.
**Remarks to; array.some**
In an array.forEach there can't used a break without using some ugly tricks (like try...catch and throwing an error), so I could use the classic variant of the for-loop. But there exists the **array.some** method this loops like a forEach-loop but there had only one of the elements to be return true so the result is true.
Example:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// checks whether an element is even
const even = (element) => element % 2 === 0;

console.log(array.some(even));
```

Here is the code of the working algorithm.

```js
var wordBreak = function(s, wordDict) {  
    if (!wordDict || wordDict.length === 0) return false;
    while (s.length > 0) {
        let test = wordDict.some( (word,index) => {
            if (s.indexOf(word)===0) {
                s_new = s.substr(word.length);
                return wordBreak(s_new, wordDict);
            }
        });
        if (!test ) return false;
        s=s_new;
    }
    if (s.length === 0) return true;    
}

s = "leetcode"; wordDict = ["leet", "code"];
console.log(wordBreak(s, wordDict));

s = "applepenapple"; wordDict = ["apple", "pen"];
console.log(wordBreak(s, wordDict));

 s= "cars"; wordDict = ["car","ca","rs"];
 console.log(wordBreak(s, wordDict));
```

Comment: Could you please explain the some method?

Comment: By the way, it fails for the input s= "cars" wordDict = ["car","ca","rs"]. It should be true.

Comment: Ok with this it's getting much more complicatted and I have to look for it. That was not clear from the question that you want this too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained it better. I'm thinking about having a hash table tisane the words of the dictionary, but it isn't clear to me yet

Comment: @myTest532 myTest532 I extended the code for the new situation and explained the some-method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordBreak(dict, str){
  if (!str){
    return true;
  }

  for (const word of dict){
    if (str.startsWith(word)){
      return wordBreak(dict, str.substring(word.length, str.length))
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

You could also probably optimize the loop over dict by pre-sorting the array and using binary search, but hopefully this gets the point across.

Comment: It returns str.startsWith is not a function

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 According to MDN's compatibility data (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) that should only happen in Internet Explorer. You can replace the startsWith call with `str.substring(0, word.length) === word`.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd be looking for a Dynamic Programming solution, we'd use an array for recording, and then we'd loop through and keep track of the word.

This'll pass through in JavaScript:

```
const wordBreak = function(s, wordDict) {
    const len = s.length
    const dp = new Array(len + 1).fill(false)
    dp[0] = true
    for (let i = 1; i < len + 1; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (dp[j] === true && wordDict.includes(s.slice(j, i))) {
                dp[i] = true
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[s.length]
}
```

In Python, we would have used a list (which is similar to an array of JavaScript) with the same size as our string:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, words):
        dp = [False] * len(s)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for word in words:
                k = i - len(word)
                if word == s[k + 1:i + 1] and (dp[k] or k == -1):
                    dp[i] = True
        return dp[-1]
```

Similarly in Java, we'd have used a `boolean[]`:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final boolean wordBreak(
        String s,
        List<String> words
    ) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        final int len = s.length();
        boolean[] dp = new boolean[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                final String sub = s.substring(j, i + 1);

                if (words.contains(sub) && (j == 0 || dp[j - 1])) {
                    dp[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return dp[len - 1];
    }
}
```

Here is LeetCode's DP solution:

[image]

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        Set<String> wordDictSet=new HashSet(wordDict);
        boolean[] dp = new boolean[s.length() + 1];
        dp[0] = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (dp[j] && wordDictSet.contains(s.substring(j, i))) {
                    dp[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[s.length()];
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/discuss) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: I mean, your understanding and approach for the problem, not the leetcode solution or someone else leetcode solution